# Match/group duplicate rows (indices)

Tags: r

**How can I efficiently match/group the indices of duplicated rows?**

Let's say I have this data set:

```
set.seed(14)
dat <- data.frame(mtcars[sample(1:5, 14, TRUE), ])[sample.int(14), ]
rownames(dat) <- NULL
dat 

##     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## 1  22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## 2  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## 3  18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## 4  22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## 5  22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## 6  22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## 7  18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## 8  18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## 9  22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## 10 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## 11 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## 12 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
## 13 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## 14 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

I can find all the indices of duplicates (including the first duplicate) using

```
which_duplicated <- function(dat){
    which(duplicated(dat) | duplicated(dat[nrow(dat):1, ])[nrow(dat):1])
}

which_duplicated(dat)

## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 13
```

But I want to be able to match those indices up as seen below:

```
list(
    c(2, 13),
    c(1, 4, 5, 6, 9),
    c(3, 7, 8, 10, 11)
)
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: slow but `Filter(function(x) length(x) > 1, by(dat, as.list(dat), rownames))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a possibility using "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, c("GRP", "N") := .(.GRP, .N), by = names(dat)][
                   N > 1, list(list(.I)), by = GRP]
##    GRP             V1
## 1:   1      1,4,5,6,9
## 2:   2           2,13
## 3:   3  3, 7, 8,10,11
```

The basic idea is to create a column that "groups" the other columns (using `.GRP`) as well as a column that counts how many duplicate rows there are (using `.N`), then filtering anything that has more than one duplicate, and putting the "GRP" column into a `list`.

Answer (score 10):

We can use `dplyr`.  Using a similar methodology as @AnandaMahto's post, we create a row index column name (`add_rownames(`), group by all the columns, we `filter` the dataset with number of rows in each group greater than 1, `summarise` the 'rowname' to a `list` and extract that `list` column.

```
library(dplyr)
add_rownames(dat) %>% 
      group_by_(.dots= names(dat)) %>% 
      filter(n()>1) %>%
      summarise(rn= list(rowname))%>%
      .$rn
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "3"  "7"  "8"  "10" "11"

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "2"  "13"

 #[[3]]
 #[1] "1" "4" "5" "6" "9"
```

Comment: Both solutions are excellent (same logic that I would not have thought of on my own) and efficient.  I marked Ananda's solution with green tick as he has first with the logic.  Thank you +1