# R - find and list duplicate rows based on two columns

Tags: r

Using R.  Base package, dplyr, or data.table are all okay for me to use.  My data is ~1000 rows x 20 columns.  I expect about 300 duplicates.

I'd like to do something like the following, but with one alteration:

[Match/group duplicate rows (indices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314490/match-group-duplicate-rows-indices)

I'd like to find, not fully duplicated rows, but rows duplicated in two columns.
For example, given this input table:

```
File     T.N     ID     Col1     Col2
BAI.txt   T      1       sdaf    eiri
BAJ.txt   N      2       fdd     fds
BBK.txt   T      1       ter     ase
BCD.txt   N      1       twe     ase
```

If I want to find duplicates in T.N & ID only, I'd end up with the following table:

```
File     T.N     ID     Col1     Col2
BAI.txt   T      1       sdaf    eiri
BBK.txt   T      1       ter     ase
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is an option using `duplicated` twice, second time along with `fromLast = TRUE` option because it returns TRUE only from the duplicate value on-wards

```
dupe = data[,c('T.N','ID')] # select columns to check duplicates
data[duplicated(dupe) | duplicated(dupe, fromLast=TRUE),]

#     File T.N ID Col1 Col2
#1 BAI.txt   T  1 sdaf eiri
#3 BBK.txt   T  1  ter  ase
```

Comment: This is the only one so far that doesn't seem to end up with random singles.  Others seem to have issues with if the ID column matches but the T.N one doesn't (when I try on my real data).

Answer (score 8):

I have found this to be an easy and useful method.

```
tr <- tribble(~File,     ~TN,     ~ID,    ~Col1,     ~Col2,
              'BAI.txt',   'T',      1,       'sdaf',    'eiri',
              'BAJ.txt',   'N',     2,      'fdd',     'fds',
              'BBK.txt',   'T',      1,       'ter',     'ase',
              'BCD.txt',   'N',      1,       'twe',     'ase')

group_by(tr, TN, ID) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   TN, ID [1]
  File    TN       ID Col1  Col2 
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 BAI.txt T         1 sdaf  eiri 
2 BBK.txt T         1 ter   ase
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution is `find_duplicates` from `hablar`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(hablar)

df <- fread("
  File     T.N     ID     Col1     Col2
  BAI.txt   T      1       sdaf    eiri
  BAJ.txt   N      2       fdd     fds
  BBK.txt   T      1       ter     ase
  BCD.txt   N      1       twe     ase
            ")

df %>% 
  find_duplicates(T.N, ID)
```

which returns the rows with duplicates in T.N and ID:

```
  File    T.N      ID Col1  Col2 
  <chr>   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>
1 BAI.txt T         1 sdaf  eiri 
2 BBK.txt T         1 ter   ase
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the selected columns to create the index you want to subset on

```
data <- read.csv()
data <- data[which(duplicated(data[,c('T.N','ID')])==TRUE),]
```

Comment: This works well.  You forgot a closing parenthesis.  data<-data[which(duplicated(data[,c('T.N','ID")])==T),]

Comment: The result is not exactly what requested by OP